# Ruby on Rails: How to 1) READ JSON from URL, then 2) GET the desired data, and 3) ADD create new record to the database

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I want to:

1. READ JSON from URL
2. GET the desired data
3. ADD (create) new record to the database

### 1. READ JSON from URL

I have an URL that returns JSON data. You can see it [here](http://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/3661112054465.json). How to read that from view (`.html.erb`) and controller (`.rb`)?

I've read [this](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/JSON.html) but I didn't know where and how to use it.

### 2. GET the desired data

If you see [this json link](http://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/3661112054465.json), you'll find that there's a lot of data in it. I just want to get some of the data like **product_name, image_url, description**. How can I extract them?

### 3. ADD (create) new record to the database

I used `rails g  scaffold ...` to create the CRUD by default. But in this case, I cannot use that. The new record must be created based on the submitted URL, not by inputting it manually.

How to do this in controller (`.rb`):

```
# POST /products or /products.json
def create

  # I want something like this to read JSON
  parsedJson = JSON_fromURL('http://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/3661112054465.json')

  # and I want something like this to create record
  product_params.product_name = parsedJson['product_name']
  product_params.image_url = parsedJson['image_url']
  product_params.description = parsedJson['description']
  @product = Product.new(product_params)

  ...
  
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use httparty gem for making API call and getting results from it as below:

```
def create
  URL = "http://world.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/3661112054465.json"
  response = HTTParty.get(url).parsed_response 
  
  product_params = {
    name: response['product']['product_name'], 
    image_url = response['product']['image_url'],
    description = response['product']['description']
  }
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  @product.save
end
```

Please read more about [HTTParty Gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty)

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

So, I actually found the answer myself.

### 1. READ JSON from URL

I found this answer from stackoverflow, but I forgot the source link.

To read the JSON from URL, do this:

In controller `.rb`:

```
def index
    ...
    require 'net/http'
    source = "http://your_link.json"
    resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(source))
    data = resp.body
    data = JSON.parse(data)
    ...
end
```

Still in controller, to debug the JSON in `data` variable, I used `abort` combined with `.inspect` like this:

```
abort data.inspect
```

### 2. GET the desired data

This is actually same for almost all programming language. To access JSON `data` variable in controller `.rb`, do this:

```
@product = Product.new
@product.brands = data["brands"]
@product.categories = data["categories"]
@product.image_url = data["image_url"]
```

### 3. ADD (create) new record to the database

In controller `.rb`:

```
@product.save
```